# Proving $\lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{1}{n^p}=0$ for $p > 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I'm trying to prove 3.20a) from baby Rudin. We are dealing with sequences of real numbers.

> **Theorem.**
>
> $$\lim_{n \to {\infty}} \frac{1}{n^p} = 0; \hspace{30 pt}\mbox {$p > 0$}$$
>
> **Proof.** Let $\epsilon > 0$. Because of the Archimedan property of real numbers, there exists an $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $n_0 \geq N$ implies $\frac{1}{n_0} < \epsilon$ and thus implies $n_0 > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$. Thus $\exists n \geq n_0 : n > (\frac{1}{\epsilon})^k$ where $k$ is any number. For the interesting case, pick $k = \frac{1}{p}$ where $p > 0$. Thus $n > (\frac{1}{\epsilon})^{\frac{1}{p}}$ implies $$\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}} \Longrightarrow \frac{1}{n^p} < \epsilon$$
>
> which further implies $d(n, N) < \epsilon$. QED.

Comment: Your title is bugged.  It is unclear exactly what you're asking.  "where $k$ is any number" doesn't make sense - what about negative $k$?

Comment: Are you asking for us to check this proof? I notice one mistake: just because $n>1/\epsilon$ does not imply $n>(1/\epsilon)^k$ for all $k$. For example, let $\epsilon=2,n=1,k=0$.

Comment: @AlexBecker: that's not what I said. There exists an $n \geq N$....we also assumed $k > 0$ because $\frac{1}{p} > 0$.

Comment: How about showing $x^p \rightarrow \infty$ using L'Hopital for $x^{p+1}/x$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @StefanSmith: Fixed the title

Comment: @DonLarynx You should rephrase it then, because as written it looks like the same choice of $n$ suffices.

Comment: @Alex: Fixed it.

Comment: Looks good to me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach: you can show $x^p \rightarrow \infty $ as $x\rightarrow \infty$. Rewrite as $$\frac {x^{p+1}}{x}$$ , which is an indeterminate $\infty/\infty$ , and use L'Hopital, to get $$\frac {(p+1)x^{p}}{1} $$. Since $p$ is fixed and $p+1>1$, you can show this goes to $\infty$ , and then $1/x^p\rightarrow 0$

Comment: Do you mean $px^{p-1}$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I fixed a few others too.

Comment: Neat proof. Can I use this in any geometric series?

Comment: As long as you have an indefinite limit and can use L'Hopital, it will work.

Answer (score 2):

We need to show that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists an $N > 0$ such that $$n>N\implies|1/n^p|=1/n^p < \varepsilon$$

Suppose no $N$ existed. Then for all natural numbers $n$, $1/n^p \geq \varepsilon$, so $n^p \leq 1/\varepsilon$. This implies that for all natural numbers, $n \leq (1/\varepsilon)^{1/p}$ meaning that $\mathbf{N}$ is bounded, a contradiction. Therefore, some $N$ must exist. $\square$